# Caught between two offers

Tags: job-offer, career-development

I'm currently working in a multinational company branch office located in my country (Not USA) as a software developer. Around ten days ago, another company approached me for an outsource position. I made an interview with the place they wanted to send me as an outsource and yesterday they came with an official offer letter.

Their offer is 180% of my current salary, a 80% increase. (82 to be precise.). They are using older technologies but they are part of one of the biggest (if not "the biggest") corporations of my country.

Today my current company made a counter offer and matched their offer.

I've been working here for slightly over 1.5 years and know the team and get along with them well. When looked at a pros and cons angle, both companies look even. Only change is second one is using older technologies (that one was bugging me but I was looking at salary increase) and I'll be working as an outsource. Both companies have fairly same level of work guarantee.

A friend said if I accept counter offer, I'd be first to be let go when things change, another said "no, recruitment is a trouble and they wouldn't increase your salary and let go of you". My dilemma is,  I have no idea how staying would look from a corporate perspective on my current employer.

Edit: My first and only motivation about job change was salary increase. After I told my boss about the situation he informed me that he was in talks with headquarters about increasing our salaries to be competitive already and he'd be asking again in light of these new events.

My resignation would leave our current team with only 1 member. That might be an indicator of the reason of counter offer but on the other hand, two other members left from another team and HQ just shifted some employees from other countries instead of recruiting someone new.

Comment: The statistics say that accepting a counter offer is generally a bad idea. (80% of people leave anyway inside of 6 months, 90% inside of a year). But only you can decide if your case is different or not. Personally, I'd go with whichever job/company/role you like more (ignoring the salary) and hope it works out.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes it is actually the case. Weird, I know. I've been coming across your sound advices on workplace for years and happy to see you answer a dilemma of mine as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

1. Is the 82% increase real increase? Going from internal to outsource might mean you pay more taxes and healtcare  (etc.) out of your pocket. Also outsource means you might not be protected by typical labour laws.
2. If your current company matched theirs and keept the employment deal then even if they fired you later on you would be fired with all benefits. Being let "first when things change" is same in both companies. You can't guarantee yourself that the new company won't do the same.

Comment: A very wise warning. Also an extra thought if being paid per diem...half of the days of the year might disappear between holidays, summer time, and weekends, not counting sick days or days the project is stalled. When I was offered a per diem position when unemployed, I started doing my math in an excel sheet, and what looked a nice number, quickly revealed being half of what I got when I entered the current job. Be also aware of "hidden" taxes or rules, like having to pay VAT for working remotely to outside the European Union.

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb: Never accept a counter-offer, submit your resignation, serve your notice period and part on good terms. if you really like(d) the place, you might get re-hired at a later point of time, but do not accept a counter offer.

The way I look at it (in general, exceptions may happen):

- If you were actually happy with the current organization / work, you'll usually not look for job elsewhere.
- Once you mentioned that you're looking for job elsewhere, the company knows you are ready to move out, and they'll make all efforts to retain you if you're valuable, but also will try their best not to be too reliant on you so that you can keep repeating the resignation-negotiation-counter-offer process to increase your salary / benefits. Chances are high that in parallel to the counter-offer for increased salary, the'll also start looking for replacements and as soon as they get one, you'll be the candidate to be made redundant/let go.
- If a company is only increasing your salary / benefits *after* seeing another offer, then they don't really value/judge your contributions, and providing what is needed to get their work done ONLY when that's matched against external evaluation (of the offer). Not a good place to work for anyway.

Comment: I second this. I still am on my current organization, because I approached my superior telling him I liked being there but was getting betters offers, and they matched them *without* another offer being shown at the table. Depending on the organization, they might only be holding you now because they need you, and for instance, you wont get raises or get earmarked for being dismissed. Accepting last minute counter-offers is not a good policy.

Comment: He wasn't looking, though.  He got approached.

Answer (score 1):

You haven`t stated your country, other than its not USA.
I think it is important , because there are differences between being a contractor and permanent employee in Canada for example.

Also, there is a very different cultural aspect about accepting a retaining counter.

There is a country I know that the only way to actually get a raise is get an outside offer and then, maybe getting a retaining one, that is sometimes even lower :)

In your case, if coworkers know about this story, especially about your current salary and if their salary didn't change, there will be tension, I am not sure you want to weather until promises of raise actualize for them as well.

In your position I would have left, on as good trms as possible

Comment: Own salary is my own business, coworkers have nothing to do with it, and frankly I do not care how much they make and neither should they.